# Run Spring test cases concurrently not sequentially

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

My Spring Boot application also starts a gRPC service along with its REST (HTTP) service. I've written specific tests for gRPC and REST. When I run a *gradle test* these tests are run sequentially, however; there is no reason they can't be run in parallel.

What I'm shooting for here is a single instance of my Spring Boot application running while the tests are executed in parallel.

I've tried setting the *test* section in my gradle file so it has 'forkCount', I also tried setting options such that parallel="classes", but this produces an error about the 'parallel' being an unknown property (maybe a junit 5 thing?)

```
test {
    options {
        parallel = "classes"
//      forkCount = 2
    }
}
```

The *forkCount* option is not what I'm looking for since it will start multiple instances of the spring application.

I've also tried removing the *@RunWith* from the test classes and making a separate test class (which has the *@RuWith* annotation) that has the following method in it

```java
    @Test
    void testRunner() {
        JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.classes(), {GrpcTests.class, RestTests.class});
    }
```

But the tests still appear to run sequentially.

I've tried several other things as well, sorry I don't have all of them handy.

**Goal**

Ideally what I'm hoping for is a single instance of my Spring Boot app running while the test classes run in parallel (*bonus kudos if I can get the methods to run in parallel too*)

- Java Version: "1.8.0_171"
- Spring Boot Version: 2.0.4.RELEASE

  ---

  Per the recommendation I tried adding the

```java
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
    }
```

And adding the '**maxParallelForks**' entry in the gradle file, I had already been using the *@SpringBootTest* annotation but this behaved the same as when I used '**forkCount**` in that at least 2 instances where started as can be seen by the test shutdown log

```
2019-04-25 10:24:17.245 LogLevel=INFO   53838 --- shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down
...
2019-04-25 10:24:30.125 LogLevel=INFO   53839 --- shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down
```

You can see I get two shutdown messages and the PIDs are shown (53838 & 53839).

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine @SpringBootTest with maxParallelForks.

Annotate your unit tests with @SpringBootTest. @SpringBootTest will boot up a Spring Boot context that will be cached across all your tests.

"A nice feature of the Spring Test support is that the application context is cached in between tests, so if you have multiple methods in a test case, or multiple test cases with the same configuration, they only incur the cost of starting the application once"

See:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Add the following to your build.gradle. To run multiple test at the same time.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 4 //your choice here
}
```

See https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_test_execution

Comment: This does not work. Similar to the 'forkCount' I had tried, it starts multiple instances of the application. This can be seen on shut down as I get 2 messages from my gRPC server process:  
    `2019-04-25 10:24:17.245 INFO   **53838** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down
    2019-04-25 10:24:30.125 INFO   **53839** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down` You can see from the PID (in the double '*') they are different.

Comment: Hey Jim, can you post one of your tests that uses gRPC and has @SpringBootTest?